# Check for time if true run query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run a specific query in Oracle DB:

```
select
case substr(to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi'),1,4)
when '11:0' then (select * from <Table name>)
else (something)
end from dual;
```

Every time I run this I get "too many values" and can't solve this why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like as this

```
select * from ...
where substr(to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi'),1,4)='11:0'
```

Comment: I want to run the select Query only when the sysdate is for example 11.

Comment: do u know about JOBS?

Comment: JOBS? what do you mean?
I took my query and run it like this:
<Query> and substr(to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi'),1,4)='11:0'
it's working but currently no data in the table (will have to wait 1 hour)
but it should do the trick correct?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle can not show multiple-column/multiple-row data from subquery into a single column.

```
select
case substr(to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi'),1,4)
when '11:0' then (select * from <Table name>) -- what if this query returns two rows/columns?
else (something)
end from dual;
```

You can either use an `aggregate function` on such sub-query or simply use `CASE..WHEN` if more than one value s required in the output:

-- Aggregate function to fetch one row and one column:

```
select
case substr(to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi'),1,4)
when '11:0' then (select count(1) from <Table name>) -- aggregate function without group by 
else (something)
end from dual;
```

-- Use of `CASE..WHEN`

```
select
case substr(to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi'),1,4)
when '11:0' then <col_1 from table name> 
else (something)
end as val1,
case substr(to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi'),1,4)
when '11:0' then <col_2 from table name> 
else (something)
end as val2,
..
..
from <Table name>;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your Detailed reply Tejash!
the thing is that my select returns more than 1 column... and therefore i get the error of "too many values"

Answer (score 0):

@Tejash explained it perfectly.

Here's another way, "play" with it:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
   l_hour VARCHAR2(10);
   l_col1 VARCHAR2(100);
   l_col2 VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   WHILE true 
   LOOP
      SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi') INTO l_hour FROM dual;
      IF l_hour = '11:00'
      THEN
         select <col1 name>, <col2 name> into l_col1, l_col2
         from <Table name>;

         dbms_output.put_line(l_col1);
         dbms_output.put_line(l_col2);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;  
END;
/
```

Comment: The problem with that solution (dbms_output.put_line) doesnt return the values to the SQL tab.
the query is meant for a product called OEM/GridControl